Edit JWT token in APPFLOW using AWS Lambda
I am trying to edit a JWT token which was used to establish connection to Salesforce using AWS Appflow. But it seems like we can't directly access the token from Lambda.
I used the following code but am not able to get details of token unfortunately. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Usage
    connection_name = "VLOS_POC_Sanket" 

    appflow_client = boto3.client('appflow', region_name='ap-south-1')

    response = appflow_client.describe_connector_profiles(
            connectorProfileNames=[connection_name]
            )

    return response['connectorProfileDetails'][0]['connectorProfileProperties']

